# How to find today's data from database from two different dates?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a database `ShiftChange`, and the fields are

```
Fromdate='09/11/2014', Todate='11/11/2014',Shift='MG' and Month='11'(dd/MM/YYYY format)
Fromdate='11/11/2014', Todate='15/11/2014',Shift='AF' and Month='11
```

I want to find today's shift from these table. I tried like this,

```
DateTime today = DateTime.Today; // As DateTime
string s_today = today.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");//system date converted to given format
int month = DateTime.Now.Month;
string str = "Select Min(Fromdate), Max(Todate)  From ShiftChange where Month='" + month + "'";
SqlDataReader dr = conn.query(str);
if (dr.Read())
{
    string mindate = dr[0].ToString();
    string maxdate = dr[1].ToString();
    string str3 = "select Shift from ShiftChange where '" + s_today + "' >= '" + mindate + "' and  '" + s_today + "' <= '" + maxdate + "' and Month='"+month+"'";//checks current shift type of selected date.
    SqlDataReader dr3 = conn.query(str3);
    if (dr3.Read())
    {
        string shiftid = dr3[0].ToString();
    }
```

Here connection is my `connection` class and `query` is my (sqldatareader dr) method.When I run this query I am getting `shiftName 'MG'` but actually the shiftName correspondent to today's date is 'AF' but it not getting. I hope it is my query's issue. Please show me the error

Comment: I had a long comment here, but I lost it... anyway, the first thing you should do is start using parameterized queries and stop converting your `DateTime` values to strings. Next, note that your second query *only* uses the Month from the database... everything else is effectively going to stay true or stay false..

Comment: @Jon Skeet, why I took DateTime in string is sometimes time format may vary from each systems. Then our code shows error.  To avoid this error I jz took datetime in a string and that string value converted to a specified format.

Comment: "shows error" doesn't give enough information. *What* error? And if the value in your database is a `DateTime`, that's precisely why you *shouldn't* convert your values into strings. Do everything with `DateTime` values and parameterized SQL - that way the date/time format is irrelevant.

Comment: @Jon Skeet. Datetime shows our system date right?

Comment: I don't know what you mean. `DateTime` is just a type...

Comment: @Jon Skeet, Sir if we declared  like this " DateTime today = DateTime.Today;" it shows our system date right?

Comment: Yes, that's right. Note that it's today's date *in the system time zone*. You should carefully consider whether or not that's really what you want.

Comment: @Jon Skeet, I am facing an issue with time format. I have developed a software using with my system time format(dd/MM/yyyy) and installed in another system with different time formet(MM/dd/YYYY). When I run projrct it shows error "time format  does not match". Can I solve this issue in anyway??

Comment: You should ask this with more details as a separate question. Fundamentally you should *only* be using a string representation for user input/output - if you treat all the data as just a `DateTime` everywhere else, it shouldn't be an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you should make your query parameterized or you can prepare sql stored procedure and use that stored procedure in your code. I am giving you sql code for stored procedure here.

```
declare @month varchar(50) = '11'
declare @mindate varchar(50)
declare @maxdate varchar(50)
declare @date varchar(50)

select @mindate=min(fromdate),@maxdate = max(todate)
from ShiftChange Where Month = @month

select TOP 1 Shift From ShiftChange
WHERE @date>= fromdate and todate<=@date
and month = @month
order by todate desc
```

Btw, it's always better to use datatype date or datetime when dealing with dates.

Comment: yup I know but if use datatype as date or datetime it shows date with time. But I dont want time. So avoid this, I know only this method

Comment: are you getting any error or you are not getting any record? and what's the value of @date are you using?

Comment: for 2 rows its fine but if we have 3 rows and our third row contains fromdate='15/11/2014' and todate='20/11/2014/ and shift='MG'. this query not works.It shows 3rd row shift(MG) on today's date

Comment: updated query. please check now. instead of doing WHERE @date>= fromdate and @date<=todate do this WHERE @date>= fromdate and todate<=@date.

Comment: are you doing todate<=@date?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue with @Mukund's help. I applied his code in my project like this,

```
DateTime today = DateTime.Today; // As DateTime
string s_today = today.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
int month = DateTime.Now.Month;
string str = "Select Min(Fromdate), Max(Todate)  From ShiftChange where Month='" + month + "'";
SqlDataReader dr = conn.query(str);
if (dr.Read())
{
string mindate = dr[0].ToString();
string maxdate = dr[1].ToString();
string str3 = "select TOP 1 Shift From ShiftChange WHERE '"+s_today+"'>=Fromdate and Todate>='"+s_today+"' and month = '"+month+"' order by Todate desc";
SqlDataReader dr3=conn.query(str3);
if(dr3.Read())
{
string shift = dr3[0].ToString();
}
```